# Codeigniter 2.1 project. Error Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I'm new to codeigniter framework. I have setup a Codeigniter v2 existing projects from github and the last couple of days I have had problems with the session.php file. All th values in the session variables are empty and I get the following error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `stream_ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES ('', '', '', 1537445113, '')

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 283
```

Session create part

```
function sess_create()
    {
        $sessid = '';
        while (strlen($sessid) < 32)
        {
            $sessid .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        }
        // To make the session ID even more secure we'll combine it with the user's IP
        $sessid .= $this->CI->input->ip_address();
        $this->userdata = array(
                            'session_id'    => md5(uniqid($sessid, TRUE)),
                            'ip_address'    => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
                            'user_agent'    => substr($this->CI->input->user_agent(), 0, 120),
                            'last_activity' => $this->now,
                            'user_data'     => ''
                            );


        // Save the data to the DB if needed
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->query($this->CI->db->insert_string($this->sess_table_name, $this->userdata));
        }
        // Write the cookie
        $this->_set_cookie();
    }
```

Anyone who has been able to resolve such an error? Thanks

Comment: post some code..

Comment: Thanks for the response. What part of the code exactly?

Comment: using localhost?

Comment: No its on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

Your column `session_id` is the primary key of your table and you inserted an empty value in it once before so the second time it forbade you because the primary key must be unique.

- so you should add `id` column into your `stream_ci_sessions` table then make it as a `primary key` and `auto increment`.
- You can add `id` and make it as a `primary key` and `auto increment` from the beginning but you first you should truncate your data.

Comment: And how would I truncate the values?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` column as a primary-key and make it auto increment.

Comment: I fixed that but now I have another problem with the URL